# Can't render views of html in django

Tags: python, html, django, view, rendering

My models

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('user_type1', 'User Type 1'),
        ('user_type2', 'User Type 2'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        related_name='customusers',  # Override the default related name
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        related_name='customusers_permissions',  # Specify a related name for custom user permissions
    )
```

My views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm  # Assuming you have a CustomUserCreationForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Redirect to a success page or another page
            return redirect('success')  # Replace 'success' with the URL name of your success page
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

My html trample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">There are errors in your form.</p>
        <ul>
            {% for field, errors in form.errors.items %}
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ field }}: {{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}  <label for="username">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}<br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        {{ form.email }}<br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}<br>
        <label for="user_type">User Type:</label>
        <select name="user_type" id="user_type">
            {% for choice in form.user_type.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ choice.0 }}">{{ choice.1 }}</option>  {% endfor %}
        </select><br>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'user_type')
```

Output:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfAdU.jpg)

Comment: You don't access template using path to the template. Access path for registr view. Where is your urls.py?